# C - Convert Hex value to int and store in char array

Tags: c, char, hex

I have the following code,

```
int main(){
  const char *hexstring = "f";
  int number = (int)strtoul(hexstring, NULL, 16);

  printf("%d", number); //Prints 15
  char s[5];
  s[0] = number; 
  printf("%d", s[0]); //prints 15
}
```

I ran it for "1F" and it returns 31 as expected.

if, `hexString` value is **FF** or any other value which results in 3 digit number, `s[0]` returns a negative value.

What am i doing wrong? How can i make `s[0]` hold 255 in case `hexString` is "FF".

Comment: @babon yes.. i have changed

Comment: @babon: Something you learn once you write your very first C program.

Comment: @Olaf :) The `()` were missing when I commented.

Comment: @Lazar: The **minimum** range for `int` is -32767 … 32767. Of course you can. `char` is not `int`.

Comment: You are right, my wrong, didn't saw it is an int.

Comment: I sse. But it should have been clear. It still is obsolete: -> `int main(void)`.

Comment: How about you read about `char` and it's "problematic" nature in your prefered C book (or do a simple online search. What do you expect the code to do? Enable warnings, every modern compiler will warn about the assignment with recommended warnings enabled. Also to printf a `char` as integer, use `%hhd`.

Comment: `printf("%d", (unsigned char)s[0]);`

Comment: @Olaf result of _`use %hhd`_ is `-1`. You mean `use %hhu` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: No, I meant `%i`. Where did I write it will not? With signed `char` you must not use `u`. (That's one reason not to use `char` for (semantically) integer arithmetics.

Comment: On your platform char is signed by default, so probably thats the reason you're getting output like that, as @Klas Lindback wrote in answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because signed/ unsigned problem was discussed here many times before. This is an elementary question explained in any C book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` can be signed or unsigned. It looks like `char` is signed on your platform. In your case you want to use `unsigned char`.

Change:

```
char s[5];
```

to:

```
unsigned char s[5];
```